# How to dump output into a file rather than on terminal

Tags: shell, expect

I am using an expect script to login into a machine via serial console and reboot the machine.

I can see all the logs on terminal. Is there a way these logs are moved into log file and only display FAILURE or SUCCESS ?

Thanks for your time

Comment: Redirect the output from stdout and stderr to some other file.

Answer (score 2):

1.

```
# disable log output to stdout
log_user 0

# send/expect dialogue is logged to my.log
# The -a flag forces output to be logged
# that was supressed by the log_user command.
log_file -a my.log
```

2. For output FAILURE or SUCCESS messages you need use `send_user` or `send_tty`